# Magento 2 - How to display recent order on Homepage?

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, cms-pages, home-page

I know that the "recent orders" section is displayed on customer's dashboard. I am wondering if I can display this "recent orders" on the homepage as well?

My website requires users to always be logged in, so this shouldn't be an issue.

I have tried adding `{{block class="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Recent" template="Magento_Sales::order/recent.phtml"}}` in custom CMS page to be displayed on Homepage but it is not showing anything.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I tried myself and found out that Magento use CustomerSession which sometimes cannot get the customer Id, I don't know why this happen, but since I know this, I always turn to `SessionFactory`

[image]

One way or the other, you have to edit the code to use SessionFactory to accomplish the task. Here is how it's display in default theme

[image]